# Unity-2d Upper panel font distorted

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fuzzy text in Unity title bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175066/fuzzy-text-in-unity-title-bar)

Using unity-2d , only when I choose the Radiance theme the font in the panel becomes distorted 
.

**screenshot**[image]