# Fuzzy text in Unity title bar

Tags: 12.04, unity, fonts

Since upgrading to precise, the text in the Unity title bar is fuzzy. I thought this might be my general font settings, but Window titles, which seem to use the exact same font, don't have this problem at all. Here's a screenshot, showing the Unity title bar just above a window title bar showing the same text:

[image: Image and video hosting by TinyPic]

If you zoom in, you can see a green shadow effect in the Unity title bar text.

Comment: This bug is present in Unity 3D as well. The "solutions" proposed here improve the situation but don't solve it. The text remains a bit blurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is likely to be this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/977080) which is specific to using the theme *Radiance* in Unity-2D.

If it is then there is a workaround you can try.

Some before and after screen-shots will help here with this method:

*before*

[image]

*after*

[image]

**how did I do that**

Themes are described in text files in the folder `/usr/share/themes`.  Specifically themes use what is termed *Content Style Sheets* to define what they should look like.

Since these are text files - you can edit and change these easily.

First you have a choice - you can edit the files directly - or via a copy in your own home folder.

If you edit the files directly, then an update to the theme will overwrite all of your good work ... but then again - it may be the update you are looking for.

Lets assume you want a user specific theme.  The following commands copies the Radiance theme into your home folder.

Lets open a terminal and copy and paste the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.themes
cp -r /usr/share/themes/Radiance ~/.themes
gedit ~/.themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css
```

What you want to edit is in this section of the file:

[image]

You need to add `text-shadow: none;` to this section (i.e. between the `{` and `}` curly brackets) so that it now looks like:

[image]

Logout and login to see the change take effect.

Answer (score 8):

This is currently being [tracked as a problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/986865) with RGBA anti-aliasing.

It can be resolved by changing the aliasing value from RBGA to grayscale.

Use MyUnity (available in the software-center)

[image]

Alternatively, you can similarly use ubuntu-tweak which you need to install from the [authors PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa).

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with Unity 2D, and I'm sorry to inform you that essentially, there is nothing you can do.

Fortunately, in Ubuntu 12.10, Unity 2D has been replaced with Unity 3D (running via LLVM Pipe), so if you upgrade (when its released) you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: This is still an issue in 14.04