# Awful green shadows round the chars and icons on panel (Radiance theme, Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: radiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fuzzy text in Unity title bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175066/fuzzy-text-in-unity-title-bar)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and in Radiance theme have awful green shadows round characters and icons on panel.

[image: image1:]

[image: image2:]

Comment: Please provide information on your graphics card, and screenshots in a format of higher quality (PNG, for instance), as the JPG-artifacts might corrupt the impression.